# Positive derivative at root of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f$ has exactly one root $r \in (a,b)$. Prove that if $f'(r)>0$, then $f(x)<0$ for all $x \in (a,r)$, and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (r,b)$.

Despite this being intuitively obvious, I'm having difficulties with the proof. Here is my most recent idea.

For $x \in [a,r)$, we have either $f(x)<0$ or $f(x)>0$. If $f(x)>0$, then by the MVT, we have $f'(\alpha)=-f(x)/(r-x)<0$ for some $\alpha \in (x,r)$. Using Darboux's theorem, it follows that there is some $\beta_1 \in (\alpha,r)$ such that $f'(\beta_1)=0$. Repeating this process on the interval $(\beta_1,r$), we produce a $\beta_2 \in (\beta_1,r)$ with $f'(\beta_2)=0$. Continuing, we have a sequence $(\beta_n)\rightarrow r$ with the property that $f(\beta_n) \rightarrow f(r)=0$ (by continuity) and $f'(\beta_n)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It feels like there should be some contradiction lurking around in here somewhere, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x) = x-x^3$ is differentiable on $[-1, 1]$, has a single root in $(-1, 1)$, has positive derivative at the origin, but is neither strictly negative on $[-1, 0)$ nor strictly positive on $(0, 1]$. So, the most you can ask for is the conclusion on the *open* intervals $(a, r)$ and $(r, b)$.

It should be clear that $f$ cannot switch sign on $(a, r)$ lest it have a root there by IVT; same goes for $f$'s sign on $(r, b)$. So, all we have to show is the existence of just *one* $x_0$ in $(a, r)$ such that $f(x_0) < 0$ and just *one* $x_1$ in $(r, b)$ such that $f(x_1) > 0$.

By definition of the derivative, $$f'(r) = \lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)-f(r)}{x-r} = \lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)}{x-r} > 0.$$ By definition of the limit, taking $\varepsilon = f'(r)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x - r| < \delta$ implies $$\Bigg|\frac{f(x)}{x-r}-f'(r)\Bigg| < \varepsilon,$$
or
$$-\varepsilon + f'(r) < \frac{f(x)}{x-r} < \varepsilon + f'(r).$$
We are only interested in the lower bound, which equals 0 by our choice of $\varepsilon$. 
Therefore, any $x$ within $\delta$ of $r$ (but not equal to $r$) makes the quantity $f(x)/(x-r)$ positive.

Now pick any $x_0$ in $(a, r)\cap(r-\delta, r)$ and pick any $x_1$ in $(r, b)\cap(r, r+\delta)$. Then $x_0 - r$ being negative implies $f(x_0)$ is negative (since $f(x_0)/(x_0-r)$ is positive) whereas $x_1 - r$ being positive implies $f(x_1)$ is positive (for the analogous reason).

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks! I assume you mean $f(x)/(x-r)<\varepsilon+f'(r)$.

Comment: Yes, that plus sign is amiss! Fixed.

Comment: Very nicely done indeed, you got my vote, ***plus one!!!***  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Function $f$ localy behaves as $f'(r)(x-r)+o(x-r)$, but because $f'(r)>0$ it is locally increasing, hence negative in some $(r-\delta,r)$ and positive in $(r,r+\delta)$. But it is continuous and there are no more roots, hence it remains negative (and positive) on whole intervals in question.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling I am over-complicating things. I guess what I want is a more formal proof of the "$f'(r)>0$ implies $f$ is negative in $(r-\delta,r)$ and positive in $(r,r+\delta)$" part.

Comment: @stochasm E.g., $f'(r)(x-r)$ is positive for $x>r$. Even if $o(x-r)$ is negative, it tends to 0 quicker than $x-r$, hence sum of them is positive for $(r,r+\delta)$, where $\delta$ can be chosen from definition of $o(.)$. Would it be enough?