# C1 function with strictly positive derivative at its root(s); can I prove that $x<y,\;f(x) > 0 \Rightarrow f(y) > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is somehow related to 
[Positive derivative at root of $f$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070050/positive-derivative-at-root-of-f)  but yet slightly different.

Let $f$ be a C1 function in $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, not necessarily monotonic but with the property that $f'(x) > 0 \;\; \forall \, x: f(x) = 0$. In other words, the function has strictly positive derivative at all its roots (well, intuitively, there can be at most one, but this has to be proven).

I need to show that given $x,y \in (a,b)$ with $x<y$, the following holds:

$f(x) > 0 \Rightarrow f(y) > 0$ and

$f(y) < 0 \Rightarrow f(x) < 0$.

The proof would be straightforward if there was a kind of Bolzano's theorem on steroids that for C1 functions says that given $x<y,\;\; f(x) > 0,\;\; f(y) < 0$, there must be a point in $(x,y)$ with value zero *and non-positive derivative*. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any such theorem. Applying both Bolzano's theorem and the mean value theorem, one can say that there is point taking value zero in $(x,y)$ and a point with non-positive derivative but doesn't say if there is a point with both properties.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Suppose $f(y) \leqslant 0$ and let $z = \inf \{ t \in (x,y] : f(t) = 0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only show the first claim, that is $f(x) > 0 \implies f(y) > 0$, by reductio ad absurdum.

Let $a < x < y < b$ such $f(x) > 0$ and $f(y) \le 0$. By intermediate value theorem, we have a zero in $(x,y)$. Let $Z$ be the set of zeros of $f$ in $[x,y]$. As it is bounded, $Z$ has an infimum $\alpha$. By continuity of $f$ it follows $f(\alpha) = 0$ and thus $\alpha > x$. By $f'(\alpha) > 0$, we have $f(\alpha-\delta) < 0$ for a sufficiently small $\delta > 0$. Thus, there is an other zero between $x$ and $\alpha$. A contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and also thanks user72012 and Daniel )!
Maybe it's easier if we take the $\inf$ of $Z$ instead of $\sup$, like Daniel suggested? This way we don't have to make a special case for $f(y)=0$.

Comment: @LucaCiti: Fair enough, I changed it.

Comment: $f(\alpha-\delta)<0$?

Comment: @LucaCiti Yes, my bad :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ has more than two roots. Assume $r$ is a (not greatest) root.
First we claim that there exists a root $s>0$ such that $s-r=\min\left(
z-r\right)  $ : $z>r$ is a root. If not, there exists a sequence of root
$z_{n}\downarrow r$. Since $f(r)=f\left(  z_{n}\right)  =0,$ be Mean Value
Theorem, there exists $t_{n}\downarrow r:f^{\prime}\left(  t_{n}\right)  =0$
hence $f^{\prime}\left(  r\right)  =\lim f^{\prime}\left(  t_{n}\right)  =0$
which is impossible.

So now, assume there exists two roots $r$ and $s$ such that there is no root
in between. Since $f^{\prime}(r)>0$ so there is some $\varepsilon\gtrapprox0$
such that $f(r+\varepsilon)>0$ and since there is no root in $\left(
r,s\right)  $, for every $\alpha\in\left(  r,s\right)  :f\left(
\alpha\right)  >0$. In particular, $f\left(  s-\frac{1}{n}\right)  >0$. Hence
there exists a sequence $s_{n}\in\left(  s-\frac{1}{n},s\right)  $ such that
$f\left(  s_{n}\right)  =\frac{f(s)-f\left(  s-\frac{1}{n}\right)  }{s-\left(
s-\frac{1}{n}\right)  }<0$ so $f^{\prime}(s)=\lim f^{\prime}(s_{n})\leq0$
which is impossible.

In other words, $f$ has at most one root.

Now suppose $x<y$ and $f(x)>0>f(y),$ then the only root $r$ is in between $x$
and $y.$ But again there is some $\varepsilon\gtrapprox0$ such that
$f(r+\varepsilon)>0>f(y)$ so by MVT, there exists some $s\in\left(
r+\varepsilon,y\right)  $ such that $f\left(  s\right)  =0$ which is impossible.